# how to get a value from the results of another column calculation in same table

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I tried to retrieve a value from the calculation of several columns,

in this case try to apply the formula "(a + (a / 25 * b)) - c" to be processed using sql language which I will use in codeigniter.

I also tried using "derived table" like `SELECT .... FROM (SELECT... FROM...) AS dt`
but I had difficulty when applying it to my case in codeigniter

```
private function _get_datatables_query(){
            $intvl = '2';
            $tgl_stok = '2019-09-30';

            $this->db->SELECT('p.hso, p.no_part, p.nama_part, jml, sp.oh, sum(p.qty)+(sum(p.qty)/25*$intvl)-sp.oh as suggest');
            $this->db->FROM('penjualan p');
            $this->db->JOIN('stok_part sp', 'sp.no_part = p.no_part', 'left');
            $this->db->WHERE("sp.tgl = '$tgl_stok' AND p.tgl BETWEEN DATE_SUB('$tgl_stok', INTERVAL $intvl DAY) AND '$tgl_stok'");
            $this->db->GROUP_BY('p.no_part');
            //...other code...
        }
```

I want a column with the alias `suggest` in the code to produce a calculated value of several other columns

I know writing code that I created is not in accordance with the rules of writing SQL, I tried a number of ways but it did not work. I am very grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of var you should use parameter  in this way you can easly pass the value you need  and avoid sqlinjection eg:

```
        $sql = "SELECT p.hso, p.no_part, p.nama_part, jml, sp.oh, sum(p.qty)+(sum(p.qty)/25*?)-sp.oh as suggest
                FROM enjualan p 
                LEFT JOIN stok_part sp ON  sp.no_part = p.no_part
                WHERE sp.tgl = ?  AND p.tgl BETWEEN DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL ? DAY) AND ?
                GROUP BY p.no_part";

        $this->db->query($sql, array($intval,$tgl_stok, $tgl_stok, $intvl, tgl_stok ));

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I have found my mistake, the problem is in the sql query that I made.

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this case.

the problem is in my query:

```
$this->db->SELECT('p.hso, p.no_part, p.nama_part, jml, sp.oh, sum(p.qty)+(sum(p.qty)/25*$intvl)-sp.oh as suggest');
```

and replace it with

```
$this->db->SELECT("p.hso, p.no_part, p.nama_part, sum(p.qty) as jml, sp.oh, sum(p.qty)+(sum(p.qty)/25*'$intvl')-sp.oh as s_po");
```

my mistake was writing quotation marks in the query